# OSX In-App purchase transactions never complete or fail

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase

We had reports of users being unable to purchase the IAP in our game. We did some research and found that our missing internet connection messaging left a lot to be desired so we fixed that up. We found a very curious problem however that is leaving me baffled. If connection drops out during a purchase then all future purchases *on that account* will neither fail nor complete.

We start the purchase using:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment].
```

This will start the process of triggering popups to sign-in and complete the purchase. If the connection drops out shortly after the login panel goes away then the transaction is never updated, it never goes past the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing state.

This only works(breaks) if the connection drops out in a way that doesn't signal a reachability change, it's easily replicated by using the [Network Link Conditioner](https://davidmichaelross.com/blog/apples-network-link-conditioner/) by setting a high packet loss (50-100% works). It's worth noting that we was able to replicate this on a laptop by moving around our office building into poor wifi areas. IAP works fine in solid network conditions.

This isn't a huge problem in itself, the *big* issue is that all subsequent purchases will also get stuck at the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing state. paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: is called when the purchase starts with a blank transactionID and the state as SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing. No more updates happen.

We add the observer early (at app launch), and don't change it so there are no multiple observers. I've printed logs to make sure the queue being passed to the observer matches the defaultQueue too.

What is even more frustrating is this seems to be tied to accounts. If I log out of the store, a purchase will trigger the login, and if I login with a fresh test account it will complete as expected. If I log in with an account with purchases still in the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing state, all purchases will get stuck.

Has anyone encountered this problem, does anyone know of a workaround or have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue right now, it worked fine earlier on multiple iPhone. Now when I've changed to another wifi, I can't seem to buy any of the products, it's stuck with state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing

Comment: I am experiencing this, there must be a way to solve this! It happened first time when I got a call during purchase!!

Comment: We never found a solution unfortunately. I think the test account that got stuck did eventually unblock by itself without any intervention from us.